# How can I find the record with id where the previous status Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

please help me

How can I find this records with id and status, e.g. "d", but only one that has passed through the previous status in the past, e.g. "b", but not other way

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the previous status? Through all letters up until d?

Comment: just "d" where there was "b" in the past, but not those that are "d"  but was no "b" before

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row comparisons:

```
SELECT id, status, timestamp
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY timestamp
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( {- b_status any_row*? -} d_status )
  DEFINE
    b_status AS status = 'b',
    d_status AS status = 'd'
)
```

You can also, in earlier versions, use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id, status, timestamp
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'b' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) AS has_b
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  status = 'd'
AND    has_b > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, status, timestamp) AS
SELECT 100, 'a', DATE '2022-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'b', DATE '2022-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'c', DATE '2022-02-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'd', DATE '2022-02-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'g', DATE '2022-02-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 's', DATE '2022-02-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'd', DATE '2022-02-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 'a', DATE '2022-02-08' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | STATUS | TIMESTAMP |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | d | 2022-02-04 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b5b0977b70071a735ccad4846a911ae9)*

Comment: Thanks, but when I will that can be before "a" or "b" ?

Comment: @SQL_Python_DataScience Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with that comment.

Comment: I want id where status = "d" if in the past the status was "a" or "b"

Comment: @SQL_Python_DataScience Change `status = 'b'` to `status IN ('a', 'b')`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this solution using **EXISTS** clause.

```sql
select t1.ID, t1.status, t1.timestamp
from Your_Table t1
where t1.status = 'd'
and exists (
    select null 
    from Your_Table t2 
    where t1.id = t2.id 
      and t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp
      and t2.status in ('b')
    )
;
```

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=015ed4f6668494f0070761ce6f911821)